# I'm having trouble deploying a java application with Kafka to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I'm trying to launch a Java application that supports Kafka to AWS, and Elastic Beanstalk is throwing an error - "None of the instances are sending data."

I've a) set up a VPC for my app, then set up a peering connection to my MSK cluster, and indicated on each route table to communicate with one another. What else is needed to communicate?

Comment: Are the instances actually sending data?

Comment: Yo! I don't know if they are. How can I check?

Comment: maybe you should include some screenshot from the command line or aws console and let us review your eb and vpc setup (you should censor the sensitive info of course). There is not enough information for us to figure anything out for you.